# Symfony2 path to img in css file on webserver

Tags: css, symfony, assetic

I have in my css file this path to img

```
.picture{
background:url(../img/once.png)
}
```

It works on localhost, but it does't on web serwer. I keep this files on web/css and web/img

EDIT:

[link](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/53#issuecomment-1548080)  This solved my problem

Thank you all for waste your time for my problem ;).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the same webroot at localhost and on your production server. ex:

```
http://localhost/app.php
http://example.com/app.php
```

then reference your images in an absolute way

```
.picture{
   background:url(/img/once.png)
}
```

relative path in css are always seen from the calling page, not from the css location

Comment: You should configure your webserver correct, that you can omit the /web/ in the url.

Comment: regardless of the environment. on production server and localhost.

Comment: whats your root directory in your web server?

Comment: `DocumentRoot /path/to/symfony/web`

Answer (score 0):

Did you do:

```
php app/console assets:install web --env=prod
php app/console assetic:dump web --env=prod
```

?

Comment: "I keep this files on web/css and web/img" - assets should be kept within Resources/public folder. That way, when you do assets:install, assetic bundle will make correct paths. Make sure you have cssrewrite: ~ in config.yml (i think it is default)

Comment: I put file to Resources/img and /css , I did assets:install and assetic:dump. Now file is loading but is empty.

Answer (score 0):

In your layout page, try to do this:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
   {% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite' 'CSS_PATH/*' %}
{% endblock %}
```

The cssrewrite is a Twig Filter, google it for mor information.

If this doe's not work, try to:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```